# Mostrar elementos de taboas relacionadas Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenas trato de mostrar elementos relacionados de una tabla laravel 8 tengo la siguiente tabla donde quiero imprimir los datos de la bd

[image: Esta es mi tabla]

Esa tabla trato de imprimirla en esta tabla pero no mostrando los id si no mostrando su nombre [image]

PARA MOSTRAR LA BODEGA RELACIONADA TRATE DE PONER ESTO

```
{{$productos_bodega->id_bodega->nombre}}
```

Lo mismo para mostrar el nombre del producto

Estos son mis modelos

MODELO productos_bodega

```
    public function productos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
}
```

MODELO Producto

```
 public function Movimientos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(productos_bodega::class);
}
```

MODELO BODEGAS

```
   public function Productos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(productos_bodega::class);
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda

EDIT

Me aparece el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Query

```
    $bodegas = Bodega::all();
    $movimientos = productos_bodega::all();
    $productos = Producto::all();
```

Comment: $categorias = Categoria::all();
        $creates = Producto::all();
        $empresas = Empresa::all();
        $tipos = Tipo::all();
        $footers = footer::all();
        $bodegas = Bodega::all();
        $movimientos = productos_bodega::all();

Answer (score 2):

Comentarios:

1. No es necesario crear un modelo para la tabla intermedia y de ser necesario debes apegarte a lo [*indicado por Laravel en su doc.*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models), bajo este punto yo consideraría removerlo
2. Tu consulta actual: **`$movimientos = productos_bodega::all();`** te da acceso directo a los valores de la tabla intermedia pero aún deberías complementarla para evaluar por ejemplo la igualdad de llaves primarias y foráneas y en consencuencia obtener los valores requeridos
3. Retomando lo anterior, entonces yo sustituiría tu query actual [por la siguiente](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

   ```
   $query = Producto::with('Movimientos')->get();
   ```
4. Lo anterior te debería estar devolviendo una colección con todos los productos y a su vez cada objeto producto con una colección interna con las posibles bodegas asociadas
5. De tal manera que si necesitas acceder a los valores puedes intentarlo de esta forma:

   ```
   @foreach($query as $objeto) 
       {{ $objeto->claveDeProducto1 }}
       {{ $objeto->claveDeProducto2 }}
       ...............................
       @foreach($objeto->Movimientos as $bodega)
           {{ $bodeja->claveDeBodega1 }}
           {{ $bodeja->claveDeBodega2 }}
           ...........................
       @endforeach
   @endforeach
   ```

Como punto final:

Yo consideraría asignar nombres de métodos mas descriptivos y que durante la construcción de la query así como el recorrido de los valores faciliten identificar que estamos recuperando.

De tal manera que en lugar de:

```
public function Movimientos
{
    ................
}
```

Pases a algo como esto:

```
public function bodegasAsignadas
{
    ................
}
```